# Ionic - switch a function with ion-toggle

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ion-toggle for switching my app between dark mode and light mode with my two functions `( enableDark() and disableDark() )`, Every thing is alright for the code but i want that if the ion-toggle is checked that the whole app turn into dark mode and undo it if it's unchecked.... I've tried this

`<ion-toggle (ionChange)="update(enableDark())"></ion-toggle>`

It turns into dark mode when the ion-toggle is checked but, it does not turn back into light mode when it's unchecked! How will i do for being qble to switch between the two functions `( enableDark() and disableDark() )` with the ion-toogle?
Thanks!

Comment: well you are alway calling `enableDark()`, so this is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<ion-toggle (ionChange)="update($event)"></ion-toggle>`.
then in your function do

```js
update(e) {
  e.detail.checked ? this.enableLight() : this.enableDark()
}
```

Comment: Ok, just switch the position of the two functions in your code ! It's worked, Thank You